# How to align navigation links after navigation menu is collapsed using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navigationbar

I have looked everywhere for this answer and can't seem to find anything that works. I am using bootstrap in my navbar, and the navbar collapses when the window is small. When it is collapsed and then opened via the button, the navigation links are centered and each of their respective drop down menu's align to the left of the page, so it doesn't function well. I need to get all of the links aligned to the left- but only in this view (I am using nav-justified for the alignment before the windows is collapsed). How do I do this without messing up my navbar in the larger view? Ideally I would like to do this by using html & css only.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2azyxk3o/)

The html:

> Comstar, inc. Internal
>   Warehouse
>
> ```
>  </head> <body>   <div class="container" id="page-container">
>
>   <div class="header">            <div class="container">
>           <a href="http://www.comstarinc.com/"><img class="logo" src="https://www.comstarinc.com/media/catalog/product/u/n/untitled-1.jpg"></a>
>       </div> <!-- /.container -->         </div> <!-- /.header -->
> ```
>
> ```
> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
>       <ul class="nav nav-justified custom">
>       <li><a href="../index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
>       <li class="dropdown">
>               <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Shipping<span class="caret"></span></a>
>               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>               <li><a href="#">FedEx</a></li>
>               <li><a href="#">UPS</a></li>
>               </ul> <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
>       </li> <!--/.dropdown -->
>       <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#">Packing</a></li>
>       <li class="dropdown">
>               <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
>               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>               <li><a href="#">Part Number</a></li>
>               <li><a href="#">Ebay Number</a></li>
>               </ul> <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
>       </li> <!-- /.dropdown -->
>       <li><a href="#">Cleaning</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#">Recieving</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
>       </ul> <!-- /.nav .navbar-nav .custom -->
>
>
> </div> <!-- /.collapse .navbar-collapse #myNavbar -->   </div> <!-- /.container-fluid #navbar-container --> </nav> <!-- /.navbar --> 
>
>
>
>   <div class="jumbotron">             <div class="container">
>
>           <h1 class="text-center">Comstar, inc. Warehouse</h1>
>
>           <div class="container" id="jumbo-content">
>
>           </div> <!-- .container #jumbo-content -->
>
>       </div> <!-- /.container -->         </div> <!-- /.jumbotron -->
> ```

I can't yet post my css here but it is able to be seen in the jsfiddle.

Comment: There is not a link to a jsfiddle in your question.

Comment: Please post your code here, and place a correct link to your jsFiddle. This will help us see the issue. [Check here if you need formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Apologies, I went back and edited the post to contain the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To left align the link and the dropdown on the mobile viewport, add this to your CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar .nav.custom > li > a:hover, .navbar .nav.custom > li > a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
#page-container {
  width: 100%;
}
/*Header*/

.header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
}
.header img {
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 57px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 22px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
.navbar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url("https://www.comstarinc.com/media/catalog/product/n/a/nav-bar-background.png");
}
#navbar-container {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar .nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
/* Link Text Color */

.navbar .nav li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Avenir LT W01 65 Medium';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.navbar .nav li a:hover {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
/* !Collapse button colors */

.navbar button {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
/* !Navbar background colors */

.navbar .custom > li > a:hover,
.navbar .custom > li > a {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
/* Changes Nav- collapse button color */

.navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}
/* Dropdown menu anchor background color */

.navbar .nav-justified > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #eaeaed;
}
/* dropdown menu background and text color */

.navbar .nav-justified > li > .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaed;
  color: #002c66;
}
.navbar .nav-justified > li > .dropdown-menu a {
  color: #002c66;
}
/* Navbar Hover */

.sidebar-nav {
  padding: 9px 0;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu,
.nav-pills .dropdown-menu,
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:before {
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  left: -7px;
  top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 6px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  left: 10px;
  top: 11px;
  left: -6px;
}
/*Jumbotron*/

.jumbotron {
  margin: -25px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url("http://www.neyralaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/tokyo-blue-background-4547.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 725px;
  border: none;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 85px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .nav.custom > li > a:hover,
  .navbar .nav.custom > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="page-container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="http://www.comstarinc.com/">
        <img class="logo" src="https://www.comstarinc.com/media/catalog/product/u/n/untitled-1.jpg">
      </a>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.header -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar-container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-header -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified custom">
          <li><a href="../index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>

          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Shipping<span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">FedEx</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">UPS</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
          </li>
          <!--/.dropdown -->
          <li><a href="#">Testing</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Packing</a>

          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Part Number</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Ebay Number</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.dropdown-menu -->
          </li>
          <!-- /.dropdown -->
          <li><a href="#">Cleaning</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Recieving</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Location</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav .navbar-nav .custom -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.collapse .navbar-collapse #myNavbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid #navbar-container -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Comstar, inc. Warehouse</h1>

      <div class="container" id="jumbo-content"></div>
      <!-- .container #jumbo-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.jumbotron -->
</div>
<!-- /.container #page-container -->
```